# How to track if someone uploading file to web?

Tags: python, web, copy, clipboard

I'm creating a application where I track files in a specific folder if someone tries to copy or move. I'm using dump

```
@staticmethod
    def read_clipboard() -> Optional[Clip]:
        try:
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()

            def get_formatted(fmt):
                if win32clipboard.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(fmt):
                    return win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(fmt)
                return None

            if files := get_formatted(win32con.CF_HDROP):
                return Clipboard.Clip('files', [Path(f) for f in files])
            elif text := get_formatted(win32con.CF_UNICODETEXT):
                return Clipboard.Clip('text', text)
            elif text_bytes := get_formatted(win32con.CF_TEXT):
                return Clipboard.Clip('text', text_bytes.decode())
            elif bitmap_handle := get_formatted(win32con.CF_BITMAP):
                # TODO: handle screenshots
                pass

            return None
        finally:
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

But i am having problems in what if someone just upload files to internet. How to keep track of that? Is there some way to get backend service for this operation?

Comment: What do you mean "upload files to the internet"?  Are you proposing that you should track any file uploaded anywhere on the internet by anybody?

Comment: If someone uploads to google drive or dropbox. I want to know about windows backend process for this , so i can track.